# How to configure a Linux device to appear in Windows Network Explorer with "View device webpage" option?

Tags: windows, networking, raspberry-pi, samba, smb

I am setting up a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B to serve up and host a local web page at its IP address and I would like the device to appear under the "Other Devices" category of Windows Network Explorer.

I have currently configured Samba on the Raspberry Pi. The device successfully appears in Windows Network Explorer under the "Computer" category. The Raspberry Pi is essentially network-attached storage (NAS) right now.

[https://i.imgur.com/95HiKwf.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI40g.png)

The expected behavior is not to configure the Raspberry Pi as a file share or NAS but to be able to open Windows Network Explorer from a PC on the same network, see the device, right-click on it, and be able to click on the "View device webpage" or "Properties" options.

[https://i.imgur.com/yainEcE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnmMd.png)

This seems to be common functionality in Network Explorer shared among printers, cameras, and multi-function devices that host local web pages.

Is SMB the right tool to accomplish this task?